# Open PDF files from storage on React-Native

Tags: pdf, react-native

I need to open PDF files from storage. Using Expo 31.

I found [rn-pdf-reader-js](https://github.com/xcarpentier/rn-pdf-reader-js) , but seesm it's dont work after last Expo update(31 version), I have error when I try to open pdf using `<PDFReader />`.

I tried [react-native-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf), but cant link `react-native link rn-fetch-blob`.
I have error:

> "rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: Cannot
>   read property 'pbxprojPath' of null".

Then I used [react-native-view-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-pdf), doesn't work too. 
Who can tell me how to open PDF files? Which exactly works now, and will work on all versions of Android (5+) and IOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[react-native-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf) works fine for me on both iOS and Android. To fix the issue with it you mentioned,

> rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: Cannot
>   read property 'pbxprojPath' of null

It seems upgrading your react-native will resolve it.

Running `react-native upgrade` and then `react-native link` should do the trick.

Comment: Seems it's dont work with Expo. So I must disable Expo? How should I do it? In official facebook github new app only with Expo.

Comment: @АлексейПередерий Expo is not the only way to create a new app, as you can see here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started you can use two methods to create a new app. Refer to this link for dealing with expo and linking problem https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19008

Comment: Trying to do yarn remove react-native
yarn add react-native, npm update, nothing working. After that expo dont compile app. So only 1 variant - remove Expo and use native?

Comment: If you want to use `react-native-pdf` you’ll have to eject your expo app https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject this isn’t a decision you should take lightly. Make sur should weigh up the pros and cons before doing so.